# How to ask subject of call to recruiter?

Tags: work-environment, email

I finished an interview process with a company, and today I received an email from my recruiter regarding a quick call. However, I was not aware of this stage and don't know what is the focus/subject of this call.

My question is how do I ask her without being impolite or confronting?

I was thinking, "May I know what is the subject of this phone call?" This seems okay to me but still a little unprofessional, if anyone could help me with this, I would be grateful!

Comment: Would it not be simplest to make the call, and find out that way what it's about?

Comment: Well I want to make sure I am prepared, it could be salary negotiation or something else, I don't want to get caught off guard.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I still think you should make the call, rather than attempt to find out prior what it's regarding. I would be a little bothered if I'd emailed someone to ask for a call, and was then asked what the call was about. I would interpret this as hesitation on the part of the other person. Just mentally prepare yourself for a possible salary negotiation.

Comment: You may want to try https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

I've worked as contract help before.

If you've finished the process of interviewing, there's one of two possible outcomes.  Either you got the job, or you didn't.  If your recruiter is the one who arranged for these interviews, they'll want to discuss how it went and provide any feedback they've received.

The best thing I've found when working with recruiters is: stay in contact with the recruiter.  They have positions to fill and if you're pleasant to work with, human nature says you stand a better chance of being considered than if you're a jerk.  And part of being pleasant to work with is calling the recruiter when they ask you to.

When you're on the call, take the minute or two for pleasantries, and then I typically go to "So.. what can I do for you?"  That puts you in the position of offering to help someone rather than being brusque and asking "why are we talking?"

Answer (score 3):

You be polite by agreeing to the call before you ask for the agenda. I'd also give the reason why you want to know, as being prepared for the call is good for both of you. So I'd reply with something like the following:

> Sure, I'm available to talk at X time. So I can be prepared, what's the agenda for the call?

If "agenda" is too formal, then say something like "topic" or "what will we be discussing" or whatever sounds natural to you. They aren't likely to care about the specific terms you use.

I've never used a recruiter specifically, but I've used this sort of language for many, many calls and meetings. Nobody has ever been offended, and it almost always makes the call more productive for everyone involved. It's only perceived as rude when it's not clear why you're asking, and so they assume it's because you're trying to figure out if it's worth your time to speak with them or not. Make it clear you're asking for a different reason, and you'll be fine.

If the recruiter then springs something on you that you need to think about, feel free to tell them you need some time to consider it and will get back to them by X day/time with an answer. Again, I do this all the time, and it's never been an issue if I clearly state when I'll get back to them.